# Two actionBar into the same activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I need to know how i can manipulate two action bar and when a conditional returns true shows ones and the other no. 
would be something like:

```
ActionBar actionBar1;
ActionBar actionBar2;

if (condition == true) {
    actionBar1=getActionBar();
    actionBar2=getActionBar();
    actionBar1.hide();
    actionBar2.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you might be able to do something such as this in your onCreateOptionsMenu method...:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if(...)
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
        else
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily implemented with [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) in the new V21 AppCompat support library. Toolbars act as a replacement for ActionBars and behave just like any other View Elements. You can declare them in your layouts and access them from your fragments and activities.

Check out the [Official Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) from Google.